# I need to exclude js library from bundle webpack in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I need to exclude a personal js library from the bundle file generated by webpack.
My library is located on .src/assets/dkv_vueDocumentXRM.js.

My App.vue file es importing the library like this:

```
import * as XRM from ‘dkv_vueDocumentoXRM’;
```

Then I will use functions exported from dkv_vueDocumentXRM.js in my App.vue like this:

```
XRM.aFunction();
```

In order to exclude this library from bundle, I declared it as external in vue.config.js in this way:

> ```
> externals: {
>     dkv_vueDocumentoXRM: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/dkv_vueDocumentoXRM.js"), }
> ```

But I’m getting this error on building:

> dkv_VueDocumento.js from Terser Unexpected token: punc (:) [external
>   "C://SOURCES//Vue//document-explorer//src//assets//dkv_vueDocumentoXRM.js":1,0][dkv_VueDocumento.js:654,18]
>   and this compile error: ERROR Failed to compile with 1 errors 18:37:47
>
> This dependency was not found:
>
> ** dkv_vueDocumentoXRM in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref–12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref–0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&*
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save dkv_vueDocumentoXRM

There isn’t much information about how to to this on the web.
Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try lazyload ?

```
XRM = () => import('./my-component')
```

In this way library/component will load when call

Comment: Thanks for your response, but with the way you described then my library dkv_vueDocumentoXRM.js will be also bundle and minified when build the project. Don't want this behaviour. I want this file not to be minified.